# PlayFramework (1.2). Processing array of Objects in controller

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I am working a dynamic form module for an application where there is a random list of Questions that are submitted as Answers.  The problem I'm having is the Answer[] array that is being submitted is not in the same order as specified in the View.  (i.e. answer[0].value in the view goes into the controller as answer[3].value).  It appears that instead of treating arrays submitted by the view as a true array, they are going into a unordered Set, then converted back into a Array before getting to the controller.  Is there any way around this besides treating the arrays as unordered Sets and having to use a manual index.

My controller is basically:

```
public static void process(Answer[] answers){
   for(int i=0;i<answers.length;i++){
       if(answers[i].question.required){
          Validation.required("answers["+i+"].value,answers[i].value);
       }
   }
   if(Validation.hasErrors()){
     //render the template
   }else{
      //save
   }
}
```

In my template

```
   #{list items:questionSet.questions, as:"question"}
      ...
      <div class="#{if play.data.validation.Validation.hasError("anwsers["+question_index+'].value)}error#{/if}">
      <input name="answers[${question_index}].question.id" value="${question.id}"/>
      <input name="answers[${question_index}].value" value="${answers[question_index].value}/>
      <div/>
   #{/list}
```

Comment: What if you use `List<Answer>` to replace `Answer[]` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: I am using **Play!Framework 1.2.5**

You should use `List<Answer>` for controller method signature instead of `Answer[]`:

```java
public static void process(List<Answer> answers) {
    ... // your logic
}
```

And I suggest you to use *zero-based-indexing-array* on your view, because `question_index` variable on the view started with value `1`. If you insist not to use *zero-based-indexing-array*, your list size will bigger by 1 element. It is because you start with index `1`, and the `0`-th index has `null` value.

To avoid that, your view should like following:

```html
 #{list items:questionSet.questions, as:"question"}
 <div class="...">
    <input name="answers[${question_index-1}].id" value="${...}"/>
    <input name="answers[${question_index-1}].value" value="${...}"/>
 </div>
 #{/list}
```

Comment: The List<Answer> fixed the sorting issue. (also thanks to green who also pointed this out)